# Presto can't read data from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hive, amazon-emr, presto

**Note**: This is NOT a duplicate of [Can't read data in Presto - can in Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48368380/)

---

In an attempt to make my `PySpark` application (which uses `boto3`) work, I had to do following multiple times

- re-install `pip`
- re-install `aws-sdk` (`boto3`, `botocore`, `aws-cli`)

While I managed to make my application work, I ended up *breaking the communication between `Presto` and `S3`*, so that *Presto can no longer read data from `Hive EXTERNAL table`s stored on S3* (while `Hive` can)

---

Upon running a simple query like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_db.my_table` in Presto, the `/var/log/presto/server.log` file reports following *stacktrace*

```
2018-12-04T12:29:54.433+0530    WARN    hive-hive-63    com.facebook.presto.hive.util.ResumableTasks    ResumableTask completed exceptionally
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.util.EmrFsUtils
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3Credentials.initialize(S3Credentials.java:45)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.HadoopConfigurationAWSCredentialsProvider.<init>(HadoopConfigurationAWSCredentialsProvider.java:26)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.guice.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderFactory.getAwsCredentialsProviderChain(DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderFactory.java:44)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.guice.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderFactory.getAwsCredentialsProvider(DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderFactory.java:28)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.guice.EmrFSProdModule.getAwsCredentialsProvider(EmrFSProdModule.java:65)
    ...
```

*see complete stacktrace [here](https://gist.github.com/y2k-shubham/7bd6b1907d93e9c711af77e61914f6e9)*

---

I'd like to clarify that

- **Only Presto seems to be affected**; `Hive`, `aws-cli`, `Spark` etc. are able to read data as usual
- My **`EC2` instances have an attached `IAM Role`** that permits reading data from all *S3 buckets* in my account (and writing to some specific buckets)
- Earlier Presto had no complaints in reading from S3, the problem arose only after *fiddling* with environment
- Things run smoothly if I **set location of my Hive external table to `HDFS`**

---

I've been through some related links to no avail

- [Can't read data in Presto - can in Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48368380/)
- [Considerations with Presto on Amazon EMR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-presto-considerations.html)
- [Authorizing Access to EMRFS Data in Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-credentialsprovider.html)

---

[image: Environment / Frameworks]

Comment: The log shows a problem with loading EMRFS. Try disabling it (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-presto-considerations.html) and see if it helps.

Comment: For now, a simple `sudo restart presto-server` seems to have fixed the issue (the mysterious world of *BigData*..)